# Question on cosets and Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: group-theory

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|G| = n |H|$ where $n$ is a positive integer, how can I prove that there is some positive integer $k$ with $ 1 \le k \le n$ such that $x^k$ is in $H$ where $x$ is an element of $G$?

I started considering the left coset and the fact that there exist $n$ distinct left cosets but then I'm stuck. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

$x$ is in the coset $xH$. We only have $n$ cosets, so the cosets:

$H, xH,x^2H,\dots,x^nH$ cannot all be different. So there exists $0 \leq i < j \leq n$ with $x^iH = x^jH$.

Then $x^{-i}x^j = x^{j-i} \in H$, as desired.